# If substring in string, when substring has multiple values

Tags: python, string, substring

I know there is a way to work around it, but I want to understand the underlying logic as to why this doesn't work.

It's a very simple statement, and it only returns as True when the first substring in the "or list" is shown.

```
for i in list:
    if (substring1 or substring2 or substring3) in string:
        print(string + " found!")
```

What am I missing here? I would think the or conditions would equal true if any substring was found in the string. As is, I'm only coming up as true if substring1 is found in string, and no substring2 or substring3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
substring1 or substring2 or substring3
```

Assuming that `substring1` is not the empty string, this expression evaluates to `substring1` because `substring1` is truthy.  This is then checked to see if it's in `string`. The other substrings have no effect on the statement.

In other words, the `or`s are evaluated before the `in`, and the `or` evaluates to the first truthy value it finds (this is called short-circuiting). You can't use `in` that way to check whether multiple substrings are in a string.

You want:

```
substring1 in string or substring2 in string or substring3 in string
```

Or:

```
substrings = (substring1, substring2, substring3)
if any(s in string for s in substrings):
```

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning behind this, though I'm not sure why it appears to complete an incomplete condition. I would think the parentheses would keep this from resolving prematurely.

Comment: The parentheses cause it to be evaluated *first*.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> string = 'hello'
>>> s1 = 'he'
>>> s2 = 'll'
>>> s3 = 'o'
>>> (s1 or s2 or s3)
'he'
>>> 'he' in string
True
```

The problem here is that you are first evaluating `(s1 or s2 or s3)` which will give you `s1` if `s1` does not evaluate to `false`. In a boolean context, empty strings evaluate to `false`:

```
>>> s1 = ''
>>> (s1 or s2 or s3)
'll'
```

What you want is `s1 in string or s2 in string or s3 in string`, this will return true if at least one of the substrings is in the string.

Comment: What what do you recommend to best look for multiple substrings in a string while keeping code at a minimum and avoiding the above issue?

Comment: @vbiqvitovs have a tuple or list of the substrings and then use the `any` function as  kindall suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Its because python uses lazy evaluation...  for example...

```
def error():
    raise ArithmeticError

print "nothing" or error()
```

Will Print "nothing" because it evaluates to True in python code does not check error, which would ordinarily raise an error and stop the script from continuing...

```
print False or error() #raises error and breaks script
(substring1 or substring2 or substring3) #returns the first true value
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be

```
for i in list:
    if (substring1 in i ) or (substring2 in i) or (substring3 in i):
        print(i + " found!")
```

The above code can find substring when they have multiple values.

```
(substring1 or substring2 or substring3)
```

This expression will return the first item in brackets that is not null.
For example, if subtring1 is not null, it will return the value of substring1. 
When substring1 is not null,

```
(substring1 or substring2 or substring3)
```

equals to

```
substring1
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `any`:

```
if any(substr in string for substr in substrs):
  # At least one match
```